# Extracting Attribut Value Imacros With Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, imacros

I was just learning RegEx in iMacros and would like to extract the ID of this user.

```
<a href="https://web.facebook.com/guruBKjualan?fref=gm&amp;dti=634080336761016&amp;hc_location=group" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=1481093529&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22fref%22%3A%22gm%22%2C%22directed_target_id%22%3A634080336761016%2C%22dti%22%3A634080336761016%2C%22hc_location%22%3A%22group%22%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1" aria-controls="js_c" aria-haspopup="true" aria-describedby="js_d" id="js_e">Decky Zulkarnain</a>
```

In this example, extracted data should be **1481093529**

The method using of course by extracting html code, and then find matched value and extract it.

I am trying this

```
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.match(/user.php?id=[\"'](\d+?)[&]/)[1];")
```

But no luck. 
After few times, I got this.

```
SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.match(/data-hovercard=[\"'](.+?)[\"']/)[1];")
```

It does get data-hovercard attribute in a whole. Just not what I am exactly needed. But How could my previous try not working? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
/(?<=(id=)).*(?=&)/g
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=(id=))` to match but not capture as a match *id=*
- `.*` to match all characters
- `(?=&)` to match `&` but don't remember the match.

**Demo**

```js
var input = '<a href="https://web.facebook.com/guruBKjualan?fref=gm&amp;dti=634080336761016&amp;hc_location=group" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=1481093529&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22fref%22%3A%22gm%22%2C%22directed_target_id%22%3A634080336761016%2C%22dti%22%3A634080336761016%2C%22hc_location%22%3A%22group%22%7D" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1" aria-controls="js_c" aria-haspopup="true" aria-describedby="js_d" id="js_e">Decky Zulkarnain</a>';
var regex = /(?<=(id=)).*(?=&)/g;
var output = input.match( regex );

if ( output )
{
  console.log( output[ 0 ] );
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks!
It works in snippet. But when trying to add to imacros,
`SET !VAR2 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.match(/(?<=(id=)).*(?=&)/g);")`

It does returned
`SyntaxError: invalid regexp group, line 10 (Error code: -1001)`

Not sure what issues I am facing (even I am pretty sure have put it right). Does imacros thing familiar to you?
Big thanks!

Comment: @muflichkamil Sorry for the late reply - I haven't worked with *imacros*, therefore I have only provided JS answer.